# Injective Linear Mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

Could someone help me determine if the linear transformation $S(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix})= a+(2b-12c)x+(3d-a)x^2 $ is injective or not?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

We know that a linear map is injective if and only if $KerS=\{0\}$

$S(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix})= a+(2b-12c)x+(3d-a)x^2=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $a=0$ , $2b-12c=0$,$3d-a=0$

$3d-a=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $d=0$

$2b-12c=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $b=6c$

so $KerS=\{\begin{bmatrix}0&6c\\c&0\end{bmatrix}\} \neq \{0\}$ which means it is not injective